# Report parameters always using design time values

Tags: telerik, telerik-reporting

How do I get the report to use a design-time set value on first run, and then use whatever the user inputs for subsequent 'refreshes'?

I'm using .Net 4 and Telerik Q1 2013 Reporting controls.

I've created a report that has a StartDate and EndDate parameter, which is passed to a SQL query and returns relevant data.

To make it easier for the users to just open and run the report with minimal effort, the StartDate and EndDate have a default value, being set as the first and last day of the current month respectively.

This works great. However, if the user changes these values after the report is loaded, and tries to run the report for say the first to last day of the previous month, the query does not use the user-entered values. Instead it always uses the expression for what is supposed to be the default value.

The way I set the default value is by opening the ReportParameter Collection Editor (right-click in the report, click Report Parameters), and set the Value property of the parameters.

The StartDate is set to:

```
=StartOfCurrentMonth()
```

and EndDate is set to

```
=EndOfCurrentMonth()
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Stephen,

What you've outlined here works for me, are you maybe not running the service pack? I set the Value property in the ReportParameter Collection editor to both StartDate and EndDate as:

```
    ='3/1/2013'
```

The preview of the Report runs immediately with the default values. I am able to change the values and preview the report fine.

I created a Windows Forms application that creates an instance of the report. When the report first renders, it renders with the default values and I am also able to change the values in the ReportViewer as an end user and re-render the report with no issues.

```
        TopPageViews report = new TopPageViews();


        InstanceReportSource reportSource = new InstanceReportSource();
        reportSource.ReportDocument = report;

        this.reportViewer1.ReportSource = reportSource;
        this.reportViewer1.RefreshReport();
```